# From List to Json infinity loop with using Jackson

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, entity

I have a 2 tables Question and Answer. In Question table 2 fields id and question. In Answer 4 fields, id, QuestionID as FK to Question, answer and isCorrect. Very easy 2 relation OneToMany.

I create 2 entity on this tables. After HQL query

> from Question

I receive infinity loop, when try convert from List to Json. Use jackson and annotate @JsonIgnore, didn't help. Also add @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference, same problem.

Question

```sql
CREATE TABLE `question` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Question` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Answer

```
CREATE TABLE `answer` (
    `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `QuestionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Answer` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `IsCorrect` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `FK_Question` (`QuestionID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Question` FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionID`) REFERENCES `question` (`ID`)
)
```

Entity

```java
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Question")
    public class Question implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String question;

    @JsonManagedReference("question-answers")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="question")
    private List<Answer> answers;
    .....getters/setters
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question [id=" + id + ", question=" + question + ", answers="
                + answers + "]";
    }
```

Answer Entity

```java
@Entity
public class Answer{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String answer;

    private byte isCorrect;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="QuestionID")
    @JsonBackReference("question-answer")
    private Question question;
    .....getters/setters
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Answer {id:" + id + ", answer:" + answer + ", isCorrect:"
                + isCorrect +  "}";
    }
```

Conroller

```java
@RequestMapping("/home")
    @JsonIgnore
    public @ResponseBody List<Question> home(){
        List<Question> qu = questionService.getQuestion();
        return qu;
    }
```

How correct create tables or how correct create entity? Maybe some other mistakes.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This *Also add @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference, same problem* surprises me.

You can use `@JsonIdentityInfo` to let `Jackson` assign ids to each object it serializes. If one of those objects comes up again, it will use its previously assigned id to reference it instead.

Annotate your classes

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Answer { ... }
```

There are many `ObjectIdGenerators` you can use.